# how to password protect xls file using java code

Tags: java

How do I password protect xls file using java code?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Check out the Apache POI project -- http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html . That would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org). It is a Java API for Microsoft Documents, including Excel.

Even though I haven't used it myself, it seems like there is support for passwords in xls documents. If you want more detailed help you would need to be more specific, like @Sebastian says.

**Edit:**
Is the [`protectSheet`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/aggregates/WorksheetProtectionBlock.html#protectSheet(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)) function from POI maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: the password is not encrypted, which defeats the purpose

Answer (score 1):

Why not zip the file and password protect the zip file (http://merkert.de/de/info/zipaes/src.zip), using `AesZipOutputStream.zipAndEcrypt(...))`